# SealReportの利用方法について

Tags: c#

現在、C#(VisualStudio)で開発しておりSQLServerから値を取得し、帳票(PDF)を作成しようと考えています。
データベースのテーブル内から、ID、氏名、性別、電話番号を取得し帳票を作成します。
SealReportで上記の動作について実現できる方法を知っている方、解決策をご教授いただけると助かります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

※追記
実現したい動きは帳票作成です。以下リンク先の紹介にあるようにSealReportを利用し帳票作成が行えるようなのですが、その方法が把握できていない状況です。その方法を知っている方、解決策をご教授いただけると助かります。よろしくお願いいたします。
https://www.ossnews.jp/oss_info/article.html?oid=9408
https://finereport.hatenablog.com/?page=1566286401

Comment: 質問がクローズされた場合には、再投稿し直すのではなく元の質問を見直してください。 - 参考ヘルプ [どうしたら再オープンできますか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/reopen-questions)

Comment: 参照記事の更に先にあるように、開発元のTutorial [Seal Report Tutorials](https://sealreport.org/Tutorials) とかサポートサービス [Get Seal Report training and consulting](https://ariacom.com/SealReport) にあたってみてはどうでしょう？ あるいはこんなまとめもあるようですが。[Seal Report Report Usage Tutorial (1) Introduction to Seal Report](https://www.programmersought.com/article/52764663936/)